# C++ Do I always have to use std::move to invoke the move constructor?

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

"Theory" question if you will.

In order to execute/make use of the move constructor in a class, do I always have to use `std::move(...)` to tell the compiler that I wish to 'move' an object rather than copy it?

Are there any cases where the compiler will invoke the move constructor for me without the use of `std::move`? (My guess would be in function return values?)

Comment: iirc, throwing an exception is another example

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Can you explain that with more detail?

Answer (score 4):

According to cppreference.com (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor):

> The move constructor is called whenever an object is initialized from xvalue of the same type, which includes
>
> - initialization, T a = std::move(b); or T a(std::move(b));, where b is of type T;
> - function argument passing: f(std::move(a));, where a is of type T and f is void f(T t);
> - function return: return a; inside a function such as T f(), where a is of type T which has a move constructor.

In most cases, yes `std::move` is needed.

Comment: Ah, but not for function returns? My guess is correct?

Comment: @user3728501 If I understand what you're asking, it looks like the compiler will automatically invoke the move constructor.

Comment: ie; If I construct a std::vector in a function and return this vector, that is the same as return std::move(v); where v is that vector?

Comment: @user3728501 Yes (if you return it by value).

Comment: I guess returning a reference would be invalid anyway, since such a vector would be a temp object. If it wasn't (ie; passed as an argument) then I guess returning a reference would be an optimization anyway, so no reason to move anything.

Comment: @user3728501 If you've passed it in as a reference what's the point of returning it (other than function chaining)?

Comment: @user3728501: I wonder whether compilers in practice go a bit further than the standard requires when optimising?

Answer (score 4):

The compiler will invoke the move constructor without `std::move` when:

- returning a local variable by value
- when constructing an object from an rvalue of the same type

In all other cases, use `std::move`. E.g.:

```
struct S {
  std::string name;
  S(std::string name) : name(std::move(name)) {}
};
```

and

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> func() {
  auto p = std::make_unique<Derived>();
  return std::move(p); // doesn't work without std::move
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::move` is just a cast.

```
unique_ptr<int> global;

auto v = unique_ptr<int>(global); // global is a lvalue, therefore the
unique_ptr(unique_ptr<T>&v) constructor that accepts lvalue references is called.

auto v = unique_ptr<int>(std::move(global)); // move returns a &&rvalue reference, therefore the
unique_ptr(unique_ptr<T>&&v) constructor that accepts &&rvalue references is used.
```

> **When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met** and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed *as if the object were designated by* an **rvalue**.

therefore,

```
unique_ptr<int> hello()
{
    unique_ptr<int> local;
    return local;

    // local is an lvalue, but since the critera for elision is met,
    // the returned object is created using local as if it was an rvalue
}
```

Also,

```
unique_ptr<int> hello = std::unique_ptr<int>();
// we have a pure rvalue in the right, therefore no std::move() cast is needed.
```